# How can I sort / map / filter the following javascript array of objects from one format to another

Tags: javascript

I have

```
const daterange = ["2021-01", "2021-02", "2021-03", "2021-04", "2021-05"]

const personData = [ 
  {
    "2021-05": 3,
    "2021-04": 7,
    "2021-03": 4,
    "2021-02": 14,
    "2021-01": 7
    "person": {
        name: 'john',
        age: 33
    },
},
{
    "2021-05": 1,
    "2021-04": 2,
    "2021-03": 3,
    "2021-02": 4,
    "2021-01": 9
    "person": {
        name: 'sarah',
        age: 50
    },
},
{
    "person": {
        name: 'mark',
        age: 14
    },
},
]
```

I want it to look like this

```
const formatted = [
      {
        date: '2021-01',
        john: 7,
        sarah: 9,
        mark: 0,
      },
      {
        month: '2021-02',
        john: 14,
        sarah: 4,
        mark: 0,
      },
      ... ALL THE OTHER MONTHS IN THE daterange shown here 
      
    ],
```

The date range could change and if there is no data in personData then a 0 (zero) value should be allocated to each month for that person

I've tried mapping over dateRange, then looking for a match in personData for the key (hasOwnProperty) but its not working.

EDIT.

Due to Andreas having a whinge, I've added what I've got but I'm not sure it helps anyone. I'm stuck, thats the point of this right ?

```
daterange.map((date) => { 
 personData.map((person) => {
       person.hasOwnProperty(date) === true
 }
})
```

Comment: _"I've tried ... but its not working."_ - And where is that attempt? SO is not a code writing service. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"but I'm not sure it helps anyone"_ - The edit shows that you don't understand how arrow functions and the implicit `return` works. If there's a block then you have to explicitly use `return ...`. And if you use `.map()` but don't use its return value you shouldn't use `.map()` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution

```
const format = (range, data) => {
    return range.map(month => {
        return data.reduce((prev, cur) => {
            prev[cur.person.name] = cur[month] ?? 0;
            return prev;
        }, { date: month })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over months and build an object for each month by looping over the person data

```js
    const formatted = daterange.map(month => {
      const result = {
        month,
      }
    
      personData.forEach(personData => {
        if (personData[month] != null) {
          result[personData.name] = personData[month];
        } else {
          result[personData.name] = 0;
        }
      });
    
      return result;
    })
```